# Negative Array Size Exception while inserting into Hive Bucketed Table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to insert into a hive bucketed sorted table and stuck with a Negative Array Size exception thrown by the reducer. Please find below stack trace.

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in fetcher#3
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.InMemoryMapOutput.<init>(InMemoryMapOutput.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.unconditionalReserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.reserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyMapOutput(Fetcher.java:514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyFromHost(Fetcher.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:193)
```

And my table DDL is *(Only showing a subset of columns for readability. Actual DDL has 100 columns)*

```
CREATE TABLE clustered_sorted_orc( conv_type string,
                                   multi_dim_id int,
                                   multi_key_id int,
                                   advertiser_id bigint,
                                   buy_id bigint,
                                   day timestamp
PARTITIONED BY(job_instance_id int) 
CLUSTERED BY(conv_type) SORTED BY (day) INTO 8 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC;
```

Insert statement is

```
FROM not_clustered_orc
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE clustered_sorted_orc PARTITION(job_instance_id)
SELECT conv_type ,multi_dim_id ,multi_key_id ,advertiser_id,buy_id ,day, job_instance_id
```

Following hive properties are set

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

This is a log snippet from MergerManagerImpl which specifies ioSortFactor,mergeThreshold etc if it helps.

```
2016-06-30 05:57:20,518 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl: MergerManager: memoryLimit=12828540928, maxSingleShuffleLimit=3207135232, mergeThreshold=8466837504, ioSortFactor=64, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=64
```

I am using CDH 5.7.1, Hive1.1.0, Hadoop 2.6.0. Has anyone faced a similar issue before? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: if it is one time  do sorting at inset time  .

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after setting

```
hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=true
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate with more details your answer. I am having the same problem but using Apache Crunch.